# Select a line on window br clicking on it

Tags: c#

I want to make the `If condition` in the `isAT` to get the position of the line on the screen.Which mean when the mouse on the line and I click on the line I am able to select it.What I need is to able to select the Line when I click on it by the mouse.Thanks for help in advance.

```
public class MyLine : Shape
   {

       private float _endY, _endX;
       
       public MyLine() : this(Color.Orange, 0 , 0, 0, 0)
       {

       }

       public MyLine(Color clr, float starX, float starY, float endX, float endY ) : base(clr)
       {
          
           X = starX;
           Y = starY;
           this.endX = endX;
           this.endY = endY;
       }


       public float endX
       {
           get { return _endX; }
           set { _endX = value; }

       }

       public float endY
       {
           get { return _endY; }
           set { _endY = value; }
       }
      
       public override bool IsAT(Point2D pt)
       {
           if (pt.X > X && pt.Y < Y && pt.X > endX && pt.Y > endY)
               return true;
           else
               return false;
       }
   }
```

Comment: `pt.X > endX && pt.Y > endY` Should be `<` there?

Comment: if it is possible please can you explain it to me?

Comment: `pt.X > X && pt.Y > endY` checks if the point is to the right of and below the top left corner. `pt.X < endX && pt.Y < endY` checks if the point is to the left of and above the bottom right corner. However, this won't work if the line has a `width = 1` - it's really how you check if a point is inside a rectangle. Also, this only works with horizontal and vertical lines.  If the line is on an angle you'll have to do a little math.